# Preposition: Within vs In

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is there a distinction between "within" and "in" as in, "upon finding a violation within the preceding four years" versus "upon finding a violation in the preceding four years"?

Comment: It looks like your word-choice question may be deciding between the prepositions "in" and "within".  Either option fits in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you were asking only about your example, or more generally, so I’ll answer more generally. Consider these uses:

1. He hung his coat in the closet.
2. He walked in the door.
3. I’ll have it finished within an hour.
4. It is almost within his grasp.

Consider swapping the words (within/in) in each of the four cases.

1. This sounds silly, to my ear.
2. This would make no sense, unless the door is hollow, and the person
   is very small.
3. The meaning here is close, however, I’d suggest that “within”
   implies that I might have it done before the hour is up, but “in an
   hour” implies that it will take every bit of 60 minutes.
4. This is also close, but “within” carries a greater connotation of
   the distinction between “in and “out”.

Latin uses different cases for each of these (ablative of time within which, for number 3, which is relevant to your example.

I was glad to see the question, because I see “within” used excessively in my technical field, as in, “the information resides within the database” and other pomposities. This is written in "formal" documents by people who would never say, "I hung my coat within the closet", but who think it sounds scientific, or erudite, or something when written in a technical paper.

Answer (score 0):

Filming must end *in* 25 days, since the production company can bear no more shooting costs beyond the last day; however, if shooting ends *within* 25 days, a portion of the budgeted money that is leftover will be shared around among the film crew.